# UIView transform base arc

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, macos

I want to apply a transform to UIView to make it look like curve or arc from a rect (like it is).
Here are 2 images before and after.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNWxv.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA7Sd.jpg

How can I make it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Post some of your attempts and people can help steer you onto the right track. If you haven't tried anything, break the problem into smaller pieces and keep trying until you get stuck. No one is going to give you the implementation when you haven't tried anything yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Actually, I've tried to slice it before. It's can be worked on simulator, but on real device, it has not enough performance to working smoothy. So I ask the people for other solutions (like transform or other like that).
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way doing this is create the UIView and convert that to an image (UIView). There are numerous functions to transform images.

The following captures a UIView in an Image

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.frame.size);
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData *data=UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *strPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myimage.png"];
[data writeToFile:strPath atomically:YES];
```

Transforming images can be done like:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
[theImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Dear Vincent,
I really put my mind on your idea. Can you suggest to me some transforms that I can make it. I've searched on core image programming guide but I couldn't find any transform match it.